# Is there a bug in Safari with getComputedStyle?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, webkit

As I know both safari and chrome are webkit-based browsers, but when I use getComputedStyle, it looks different. Chrome, IE, FF all echo '50px', but safari echo's '10%' instead. 
That's a real inconvenience for work. 
Is this a safari bug or did I just make a mistake?

The demo test in Safari for win V5.1.7 and IOS6/7
Here is a demo:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
body{
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
}
#test{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
}
</style>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var oTest = document.getElementById('test');
    var iLeft = window.getComputedStyle(oTest, null)['top'];
    console.log(iLeft);
    alert(iLeft);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29084) that still exists in Safari 7.1. The Blink engine applied a [patch](https://codereview.chromium.org/13871003/) for Chrome to match IE9 and Firefox behavior. But sadly the change has not ported to Webkit yet.

The [CSSOM spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/) did not really define what getComputedStyle should return initially, and an some of this is [still not fully](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=16389) addressed to this day, due to the differences in browsers. It's a bit of an interop mess.

I'd say either avoid percentages, or for your example, you have to do a cross-browser compatibility [fallback method](http://jsfiddle.net/m63tH/1/) instead, by doing a `getComputedStyle` on the `body` divided by 10.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
var font = "10%"; // suppose got 10%
if (font.indexOf("%") > -1) {
    font = font.substr(0, font.length - 1);   // get the `10`
    font = parseInt(font, 10);  // convert to number
    var w = window,
        d = document,
        e = d.documentElement,
        g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
        width = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth;  // the width

    alert((font * width) / 100);  // alert (percent * width / 100)
} else {
    alert(font); // font is normal (in px,etc.)
}
```

#### [Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/retuxifa/1/edit?js,console)

**EDIT 1:**

Try this:

```
var oTest = document.getElementById('test');
var iLeft = window.getComputedStyle(oTest).getPropertyValue("top");
alert(iLeft);
```

[This again works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/m63tH/). I also tried it on [Mobile Safari simulator](http://www.testiphone.com/) which gave the correct result. But might be the simulator's mobile and you're on Desktop. BTW, are you using the latest Safari version?

Comment: Well, works but safari should do that for me, right?

Comment: @user2926630 Yep but I was just giving a workaround for that problem.

Comment: Thanks for edit, but it still alert '10%' in Safari for win v5.1.7 and ios6/7

Comment: @user2926630 Then I am really sorry I have no idea.

Comment: @HighBoots It works if you set a `px` value but not with `%`. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24486790/1647538) for reasons.